# How to reorder boxplot labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

1. I want to plot first figure with no NAs and order by median. I think I could do this by using na.omit and the code1 below.
2. How can plot the second figure by keeping the ones that are in figure1 (carA and carC) and also keep the same ordering as in figure 1.

a

```
      R   G    T
EG1   2  20 carA
EG2   4  40 carA
EG3   8  80 carA
EG4  10 100 carA
EG5  NA  20 carB
EG6  NA  40 carB
EG7  NA  50 carB
EG8  NA  90 carB
EG9   4  50 carC
EG10  8  60 carC
EG11 12  70 carC
EG12 24  90 carC
```

code1

```
ggplot(a, aes(reorder(T, log2(R+1), median, order=TRUE), log2(R+1), fill=T)) + geom_boxplot()+coord_flip()
```

[image]

code2

```
ggplot(a, aes(reorder(T, log2(G+1), median, order=TRUE), log2(G+1), fill=T)) + geom_boxplot()+coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the order from the first plot, and use it to set the limits in the second using `scale_x_discrete` (due to `coord_flip`).

```
limits <- levels(reorder(a$T, log2(a$R + 1))) 

ggplot(a, aes(reorder(T, log2(R + 1), median, order = TRUE), log2(R + 1), fill = T)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = limits)

ggplot(a, aes(reorder(T, log2(G + 1), median, order = TRUE), log2(G + 1), fill = T)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = limits)
```

Comment: I would add na.omit(a), to ignore nulll values. thanks it is working great!